# Angular Material Elements stopped working in specific component after different npm package installation

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material

I am trying to implement the ngx-markdown-editor found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-markdown-editor) into my project. My problem is, that after installing the npm package of that editor one of my other components in a totally different location stopps working and prevents my app from running. The errors i am getting are all refering to material items that are not known.

How is that possible?

I tried uninstalling that npm package and everything is fine again. Hopefully some of you are able to understand my problem. If you need further information pls let me know.

These are my dependencies before the installation:

```html
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.0.8",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.0.8",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.0.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.8",
    "@angular/router": "^10.0.8",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1",
    "@material/list": "^3.2.0",
    "@material/menu": "^3.2.0",
    "@material/menu-surface": "^3.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^10.0.5",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.3",
    "@stomp/ng2-stompjs": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "cypress": "^7.6.0",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
    "fast-text-encoding": "^1.0.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.3.2",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ngx-filesize": "^2.0.15",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^3.3.1",
    "ngx-monaco-editor": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "npm-cli": "^0.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.2",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.5.0",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "tslint-sonarts": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.10",
    "yarn": "^1.22.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.5",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "^0.1000.5",
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.1000.5",
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "^0.1000.5",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^10.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.0.8",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^10.0.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tsickle": "^0.38.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1"
  }
}
```

EDIT: Restarting the IDE solved the problem.

Comment: Seems like i just had to restart my IDE after an npm install... :(

Answer (score 0):

There are no same `dependencies` for these packages. What was your implementation for the `ngx-markdown-editor`? Are you sure the imports into modules were correct and/or added correct assets into `angular.json`?

There are some things you can try:

- Install the package again and point to the correct dependency scripts in the `angular.json` provided under [Usage](https://github.com/lon-yang/ngx-markdown-editor) section
- Make sure `Material Modules` used in your modules are imported correctly (You can make `shared.module` - which imports and after exports all needed `Material Modules` and, likewise, `LMarkdownEditorModule`. After import it into the other modules where needed)

If something else goes wrong, provide us with some representation (Like `stackblitz`)

Comment: Thanks, it was a restart of the IDE after all that solved the problem. Sometimes the easiest solutions are the ones you are not thinking of.